# Xamarin.Forms ListView Load More

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

**The Problem**

What I want to achieve can you basically see here

[image]

so when the user scrolls to the end I want to load more, because my List is very large and I want to Maximize Performance.

I'm trying to achieve this as follows, in splitting the Main Collection with the Data so that i can set the ItemSource new when the User reaches the end.

**What ive Implemented so far**

```
 public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel {

        public ViewModel() {
            Initialize();
        }

        public List<List<Usermodel>> SplitedUserLists { get; set; }

        //Main List that im Binding to
        public List<Usermodel> ItemSourceCollection { get; set; }

        public int ChunkSize { get; set; }
        #endregion

        private async void Initialize() {

            ItemSourceCollection = await LoadList();

            // Splites the list (in this case the chunk Size is 5)
            SplitedScoreLists = ItemSourceCollection.Split(GetChunkSize()));
            ItemSourceCollection = SplitedScoreLists[0];
        }

        //Gets called from CodeBehind
        public void ListViewItemAppearing(ItemVisibilityEventArgs e) {

            //Bottom Hit!
            if (e.Item == ItemSourceCollection[ItemSourceCollection.Count - 1]) {

                if (ChunkSize >= SplitedScoreLists.Count) {
                    return;
                }

                foreach (var usermodel in SplitedScoreLists[ChunkSize].ToList()) {
                    ItemSourceCollection.Add(usermodel);
                }

                if (ChunkSize < SplitedScoreLists.Count) {
                    ChunkSize++;
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

**Questions**

1. The problem with my Implementation is that the List is actually longer than the Count of the original List due to duplicates.
2. Is this the right way to achieve something like this?
3. Am I actually increasing Performance with this? I need to cause the List is 1000+ entries.

Comment: I'd question whether this improves performance, unless it's fairly expensive to load each chunk of data.  Instead I would load it all at once and use a search box and jump list to allow the user to navigate the list.

Comment: I'm loading them all once, just trying to not show them all by once. Maybe the users doesn't need them all.

Comment: as a user, I would find that really annoying

Comment: I've just checked it on the Device you as a User won't even notice it. I followed all the Xamarin Guidelines for performance increase although it is a little bit better in trying to not have lag at all. All the famous apps do have this mechanism just look at Reddit for example. :)

Comment: Reddit loads it's data from a remote source, which is different.  You said yours is loaded all at once.  If I was a user and you showed me a list of 1000 items and forced me to scroll to the bottom instead of searching or using a jump list I wouldn't be impressed.

Comment: Since xamarin forms uses view recycling, it's not actually costing you anything but the memory you use to store the data that you put in the list items. You're already loading everything into memory, so I think this would actually be less efficient. Basically, every time you scroll a view off the screen, it's recycled and used at the other end of the list and just populated with the data that should be in that cell. Doing it this way would also make any searching/filtering you do a lot simpler and easier to debug.

Comment: Makes sense thanks for the answer, I'm curios what is purpose of such a feature?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are nice tutorials on how to achieve this:

http://motzcod.es/post/107620279512/load-more-items-at-end-of-listview-in

https://github.com/jguibault/Xamarin-Forms-Infinite-Scroll

http://www.codenutz.com/lac09-xamarin-forms-infinite-scrolling-listview/

The key point is when to raise the "load more" command:

```
public class InfiniteListView : ListView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty LoadMoreCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create<InfiniteListView, ICommand>(bp => bp.LoadMoreCommand, default(ICommand));

    public ICommand LoadMoreCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(LoadMoreCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LoadMoreCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public InfiniteListView()
    {
        ItemAppearing += InfiniteListView_ItemAppearing;
    }

    void InfiniteListView_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        var items = ItemsSource as IList;

        if (items != null && e.Item == items[items.Count - 1])
        {
            if(LoadMoreCommand != null && LoadMoreCommand.CanExecute(null))
                LoadMoreCommand.Execute(null);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: what about using native android in xamarin?  Not using by xamarin form.

Comment: the Create<> is now obsolete.